# Is this the correct syntax to validate authorization of API? given().get("url").when().auth("username","pwd").then().assertthat().statuscode(200)

Tags: bdd, rest-assured, gherkin, web-api-testing

I am testing for preemptive authorization using BDD for API automation using       Rest assured. Is this the correct syntax?

```
given().get("url").when().auth("username","pwd").then().assertthat().statuscode(200)
```

Can I write `get()` after `given()` or should it be in `when()`?

Comment: Welcome to SO, do you get any error or do you want somebody to write code for you ?

Comment: I am new to BDD ,I am exploring whether we can get the url in given() or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it works for me when i use this with Testng.

```
httpreq.auth().preemptive().basic("ToolsQA", "TestPassword");
        reponse = httpreq.request(Method.GET,"/authentication/CheckForAuthentication");
```

Thanks for Asking,

Comment: Sure i will try